# Validate user input with required and optional spaces

Tags: java, string, whitespace

I'm writing a sort of quiz, where I specify the correct answers as strings. All whitespaces in the answer were "ignored" in the previous versions.

For example, if the correct answer I specified is:

```
aba
```

Then I would accept user answers such as:

```
aba
a ba
ab    a
```

Basically, the code to check if it was correct was as follows:

```
correct.replaceAll(" ","").equals(input.replaceAll(" ",""));
```

**However** now I decided I'd like some answers with **requied spaces**, where the space must be there at certain positions. I marked this space with `[s]`.

So if I want a space to be present between `a` and `b` I'd change to previous correct answer to:

```
a[s]ba
```

And then I'd only like to accept input where that space is present:

```
a ba -> OK
a b  a -> OK
aba -> NOT OK
ab  a -> NOT OK
```

I can't modify my code to implement this feature. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: If you can't modify your code to implement this, why did you ask about it?

Comment: @NomadMaker Even thogh I cant, someone might be able to give me a tip on how I could solve this problem

Comment: By not removing all the spaces...

Answer (score 1):

For your specific example you can use a [regular expression](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/).

```java
input.matches(" *a +b *c *");
```

The fragment  `*` means "zero or more spaces", and  `+` means "one or more spaces".

Comment: Great for this example. But in my actual answers there can be any number of required spaces, and anything between them. So you are suggesting I build a regex like this based on the input?

Comment: Yes, you could build a regex for each answer, by adding ` *` between every character except for the required spaces.

Comment: I think I can work with this, except that some character series (words e.g.) I want together, no spaces between letters. Like for 'good[s]answer' I cant accept 'go od ans wer'. Maybe I could split by a regex that matches words and [s].

Comment: Then you need to encode that somehow. Either by writing the answers as regex in the first place, or some other scheme of your choosing.

Comment: Based on your answer, I was able to come up with a solution! Thank you for the help. What is the etiquette in this case? I upvote you of course, but do I accept it or post my own answer, or edit my question with the answer?